# Can someone help me to program a game menu in html?

Tags: html, css, menu, game-development, jss

I'm in the process of programming a game menu in html. However, I have no idea how best to do this. I have already watched many tutorials on Youtube etc. but none have worked so far. Maybe someone can help me here and tell me how to make a game menu with a "Start game" button, a "Settings" button and a "Credits" button.

I tried to code the menu but that was completely wrong. I also don't know where in html I have to put the menu code

```js
var kugel = 0;
var player_health = 100;
var panzer_sp = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 10,
  height: 5,
  player_health
}
var panzer_sp2 = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 10,
  height: 5,
  player_health
}
var damage = 20;


function load() {
  window.setInterval(f_timer, 20);
  //______________________________
  kugel = new Array(); // neue Liste erzeugen
  //________________________________



  canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  canvas.setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
  canvas.focus();
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', f_mousedown, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('keypress', f_keypress, false);
  music = document.getElementById("music");
  panzer_sp = canvas.width / 2;
  panzer_sp2 = canvas.width / 2 - 10;

  f_draw();

}







function f_draw() {

  canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  canvas.width = canvas.width;

  var gc = canvas.getContext("2d");

  gc.fillStyle = "#800";


  {
    let background = document.getElementById("background");
    gc.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 1640, 700);
  }
  gc.fillStyle = "#800";


  //gc.fillRect(panzer_sp2, canvas.height-10,20,5);
  let img = document.getElementById("panzer_l");
  gc.drawImage(img, panzer_sp, canvas.height - 50, 150, 52); //bildergröße
  gc.drawImage(img, panzer_sp2, canvas.height - 50, 150, 52); //bildergröße

  //____________________________________________________

  //gc.fillRect(panzer_sp2, canvas.height-10,20,5);


  //_____________________________________________________

  gc.fillStyle = "#900";
  for (let i = 0; i < kugel.length; i++) {
    gc.fillRect(kugel[i].x, kugel[i].y, kugel[i].w + 10, kugel[i].h + 10);
  }
  //_____________________________________________________
}




function f_mousedown(e) {

  console.log('CLICK : x=' + e.offsetX + ',y=' + e.offsetY);
  console.log('Canvas: w=' + canvas.width + ',h=' + canvas.height);

}
//Panzer im Spiel bewegen(+Geschwindigkeit einstellen)
function f_keypress(e) {
  console.log('key press:' + e.keyCode);
  if (e.keyCode == 97) {
    panzer_sp = panzer_sp - 7; //6 steht für Geschwindigkeit(je höher desto schneller)
    player_health = player_health - 20;
    console.log(`Health: ${player_health} `);
    if (player_health == 0) {
      console.log(`Player one...its over`);
      backgroundmusic.play();
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 100) {
    panzer_sp = panzer_sp + 7;

  }
  if (e.keyCode == 100) {
    music.play();
  }
  f_draw();

  if (e.keyCode == 52) {
    panzer_sp2 = panzer_sp2 - 6;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 54) {
    panzer_sp2 = panzer_sp2 + 6;
  }
  //______________________________________
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    let t = {
      x: panzer_sp + 60,
      y: 660,
      w: 3,
      h: 10
    };
    kugel.push(t);
  }

  if (e.keyCode == 53) {
    let t = {
      x: panzer_sp2 + 60,
      y: 660,
      w: 3,
      h: 10
    };
    kugel.push(t);
  }
  //_____________________________________
  f_draw();
}



function f_timer() {
  let curTime = Date.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < kugel.length; i++) {

    kugel[i].x += 5;

    if (kugel[i].x > 1640)
      kugel.splice(i, 1);
  }

  f_draw();


  //_______________________________
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: blue;
  font-size: 40x;
}

.mystyle {
  color: #444;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.canvas {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(154, 11, 11);
}

.displays {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <div style="display:none"> <img id="background" preload="true" src="img/Marslandschaft2.jpg" width="770" height="227">
  </div>
  <div style="display:none"> <img id="panzer_l" preload="true" src="img/panzer2.png" width="70" height="27"></div>
  <div style="display:none"> <img id="panzer_r" preload="true" src="img/panzer2_s.png" width="70" height="27">
  </div>
  <audio id="music" src="Audio/fahrt.m4a">
  </audio>
  <audio id="backgroundmusic" src="Audio/backgroundmusic.mp3">
  </audio>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/myjs.js"></script>
  <title>tanks</title>
</head>

<body onload="load()">

  <div class="mystyle">
  </div>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" class="canvas" width="1640" height="700"></canvas>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Start by creating a valid page. An HTML page normally is `<!doctype html><html><head><title>Tanks</title><link.../><script></script></head><body><div></div><div></div><div></div></body></html>`

Comment: Also you cannot define your images externally and then use them in the canvas. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-displaying-an-image-on-html5-canvas-works-13e3f6a6c4bd/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that does not give errors. Try it with your own images

I also replaced the onload with an eventListener

```js
var kugel = 0;
var player_health = 100;
var panzer_sp = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 10,
  height: 5,
  player_health
}
var panzer_sp2 = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 10,
  height: 5,
  player_health
}
var damage = 20;


function load() {
  window.setInterval(f_timer, 20);
  //______________________________
  kugel = new Array(); // neue Liste erzeugen
  //________________________________



  canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  canvas.setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
  canvas.focus();
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', f_mousedown, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('keypress', f_keypress, false);
  music = document.getElementById("music");
  panzer_sp = canvas.width / 2;
  panzer_sp2 = canvas.width / 2 - 10;

  f_draw();

}

function f_draw() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  canvas.width = canvas.width;
  var gc = canvas.getContext("2d");
  gc.fillStyle = "#800";
  let background = document.getElementById("background");
  gc.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 1640, 700);
  gc.fillStyle = "#800";


  //gc.fillRect(panzer_sp2, canvas.height-10,20,5);
  let img = document.getElementById("panzer_l")
  gc.drawImage(img, panzer_sp, canvas.height - 50, 150, 52); //bildergröße
  gc.drawImage(img, panzer_sp2, canvas.height - 50, 150, 52); //bildergröße

  //____________________________________________________

  //gc.fillRect(panzer_sp2, canvas.height-10,20,5);


  //_____________________________________________________

  gc.fillStyle = "#900";
  for (let i = 0; i < kugel.length; i++) {
    gc.fillRect(kugel[i].x, kugel[i].y, kugel[i].w + 10, kugel[i].h + 10);
  }
  //_____________________________________________________
}




function f_mousedown(e) {

  console.log('CLICK : x=' + e.offsetX + ',y=' + e.offsetY);
  console.log('Canvas: w=' + canvas.width + ',h=' + canvas.height);

}
//Panzer im Spiel bewegen(+Geschwindigkeit einstellen)
function f_keypress(e) {
  console.log('key press:' + e.keyCode);
  if (e.keyCode == 97) {
    panzer_sp = panzer_sp - 7; //6 steht für Geschwindigkeit(je höher desto schneller)
    player_health = player_health - 20;
    console.log(`Health: ${player_health} `);
    if (player_health == 0) {
      console.log(`Player one...its over`);
      backgroundmusic.play();
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 100) {
    panzer_sp = panzer_sp + 7;

  }
  if (e.keyCode == 100) {
    music.play();
  }
  f_draw();

  if (e.keyCode == 52) {
    panzer_sp2 = panzer_sp2 - 6;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 54) {
    panzer_sp2 = panzer_sp2 + 6;
  }
  //______________________________________
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    let t = {
      x: panzer_sp + 60,
      y: 660,
      w: 3,
      h: 10
    };
    kugel.push(t);
  }

  if (e.keyCode == 53) {
    let t = {
      x: panzer_sp2 + 60,
      y: 660,
      w: 3,
      h: 10
    };
    kugel.push(t);
  }
  //_____________________________________
  f_draw();
}



function f_timer() {
  let curTime = Date.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < kugel.length; i++) {

    kugel[i].x += 5;

    if (kugel[i].x > 1640)
      kugel.splice(i, 1);
  }

  f_draw();


  //_______________________________
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load)
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: blue;
  font-size: 40x;
}

.mystyle {
  color: #444;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.canvas {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(154, 11, 11);
}

.displays {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>tanks</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/myjs.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="mystyle"></div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" class="canvas" width="1640" height="700"></canvas>
  <div style="display:none">
    <img id="background" preload="true" src="https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/02/88/18/360_F_302881829_9aCUDI3TnoajIVTuIFnBecAz6Wn2kQFj.jpg" width="770" height="227">
    <img id="panzer_l" preload="true" src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/719/207/png-transparent-panzer-38-churchill-tank-panzer-ii-tank-vehicle-weapon-combat-vehicle-thumbnail.png" width="70" height="27">
    <img id="panzer_r" preload="true" src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/719/207/png-transparent-panzer-38-churchill-tank-panzer-ii-tank-vehicle-weapon-combat-vehicle-thumbnail.png" width="70" height="27">
  </div>
  <audio id="music" src="Audio/fahrt.m4a"></audio>
  <audio id="backgroundmusic" src="Audio/backgroundmusic.mp3"></audio>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I code now the Menu. I mean i already programmed one but i dont know where i have to put it in the html section. Maybe there is a possibility that I could send it to you

Comment: It could live inside `<div class="mystyle"></div>` - Please reload my answer, for some reason the changes to the HTML were missing